# Extracting Body of email

Tags: php, email, encoding

I am trying to extract the message body of an encoded email. Everything worked fine for many a year but now there are some extra headings being included which have put a spanner in the works

To follow is the end of the email headers and the start of the message body itself.
When I view the email source it shows a blank line between the two sections, but when I try and split it by this, it does not find it

If I split by the first 5 characters of the message body, it actually ignores the blank line and THE line prior to that ( YamCpMIyU+au/dWzSGjp0w9hpHu/m/vs8HM=)

I am utterly confused by this and am reaching out for any advice you can give.

---

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=groups.io;
 q=dns/txt; s=20140610; t=1551842112;
 bh=QhnqlnG4IESh6eMyHbR+KrM4N9LZk0XPpXuFqpHah2U=;
 h=Content-Type:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To;
 b=DRGclGLkyYq+uYoipKgl7d7CTB3Z8MQ/SVEiJe5KwiW91BuPTXRwnTaAb9AjTa+xbxC
 1QYGocd8r8ZD2v9JRdlqLWTb9m9M91nRhO8tsbBbVK7VofmOmzYzHpVEfdQMJBo/jbth8
 YamCpMIyU+au/dWzSGjp0w9hpHu/m/vs8HM=

UGxhbmVQbG90dGVyIExvZyBmcm9tIE1hY2Fww6EsIEFtYXDDoSAtIEJSIGZvciAwNS8wMy8yMDE5
IFRpbWVzIGFyZSBVVEMNCkxvY2F0aW9uOiBNYWNhcMOhLCBBbWFww6EgLSBCUiwgQXV0aG9yOiBG
YWJpYW5vIEZlcnJlaXJhLCBSZWNlaXZlcjogIFNCTVENCg0KQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIE5pYyBTdG9y
ZXlzIFBsYW5lUGxvdHRlciBSZXBvcnQgVmlld2VyIFZlciAyLjMgDQpEb3dubG9hZCBGcm9tOiBo
```

---

Many thanks
Alexis

Comment: When I am copying this as a string, I am getting, newline characters, are they present in the original text?, also the body ends at `/vs8HM=` right?

Comment: The newline characters are indeed in the original. And /vs8HM= is actuallyl the end of the header information

The start of the body of the email is after the blank line, starting UGxhbmVQbG90d....

Comment: and do they always end with the /vs8HM=